# Do generalized Pauli Operators generate SU(n)?

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-information, group-representations, representation-theory, lie-algebra

A commonly used generalization of Pauli Operators is the "clock" and "shift" operators [summarized here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices).

Pauli Operators are generators of SU(2). Are these generalized Pauli Operators generators of SU(n)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course they do: J J Sylvester [introduced them in 1882](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/aas8085.0003.001/664?rgn=full+text;view=pdf;q1=nonions), p. 649, for that very purpose. They are a basis of all $n\times n$ matrices, and thus $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, the Lie Algebra of *SU(n)*.  A linear combination of them with suitable coefficients, exponentiated, provides all elements of *SU(n)*.

The *complete* family of *n*<sup>2</sup> independent unitary (but non-Hermitian) independent matrices
$$ 
(\Sigma_1)^k   (\Sigma_3)^j  =\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}    |m+k\rangle \omega^{jm} \langle m| ,  
$$
where $\omega^n=1$, provides a trace-orthogonal  basis for $\mathfrak{gl}(n,C)$, known as "nonions" $\mathfrak{gl}(3,C)$, "sedenions" $\mathfrak{gl}(4,C)$, etc...

It should be evident that  $\Sigma _ 1 ^n = \Sigma _ 3 ^n = 1\!\!1$,
and the braiding relation,
 $ \Sigma_3 \Sigma _1 = \omega \Sigma_1 \Sigma _3 = e^{2 \pi i / n} \Sigma_1 \Sigma _3$.

Since all indices are defined cyclically mod *n*, orthogonality follows,
$$\mathrm{tr}\Sigma_1^j  \Sigma_3^k\Sigma_1^m\Sigma_3^s =\omega^{km} n~\delta_{j+m,0}  \delta_{k+s,0}~.$$

This basis, not very popular for its lack of hermiticity, can be systematically connected to the standard Weyl-Cartan Hermitian basis.

For instance, the powers of the basic clock matrix,  $\Sigma_3$, comprising the  Cartan subalgebra, map to linear combinations of the $h_k^n$ Lie Algebra elements. For *n*=3 ("nonions") it is easy to demonstrate their mapping to the Gell-Mann matrices and the identity.

More significantly, the *n* → ∞ limit is particularly transparent in this language, identifying $\mathfrak{gl}(\infty,C)$ with the Lie algebra of 
Poisson brackets.

Comment: The generalized Pauli matrices can be used as a basis for the Pauli subgroup of $SU(n)$ (i.e. they has group properties) and also as a basis (of non-hermitian matrices, but nevertheless a basis) for hermitian matrices, so they also have algebraic properties.    See doi: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.528006  There is a pretty cool application by Zeitlin, V. "Finite-mode analogs of 2D ideal hydrodynamics: Coadjoint orbits and local canonical structure." Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena 49.3 (1991): 353-362.

Comment: Yes, thanks, Zeitlin actually relies on our paper, his ref [4](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269389910575). Neither Patera nor we, in the late 80s, had any idea about Sylvester.... It is *all* JJSylvester, if you read his notions, sedenions, etc... GL(N).

Comment: which I will do after reading those other papers you recommended on reconstructing the potential from the eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh... you can always front-load my 1989 Tahoe [summary talk](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9tahoe.pdf).... Isospectral stuff is dandy, but it can wait for a rainy day... (When Rosner, Quigg, and Thacker saw how 2 and states of the Balmer formula reproduce the singularity of the Coulomb potential, they were sold... they beat charmonia to death...).

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean "generator" in the group sense or the Lie algebra sense?

As a group, the Paulis don't generate SU(2) since the Pauli group is finite.  The same is true for the generalized Paulis.

As a Lie algebra, the generalized Paulis generate SU(n) since $\{ \sum_{ij} \alpha_{ij} X^i Z^j : \alpha_{ij} \in \mathbb{R} \}$ consists of all Hermitian matrices.